# grails expression

Tags: grails

Wondering if there is any thing wrong in this expression

```
${message(code:'${domianObject.paymentMode }.label', default:'Test')}
```

All I am doing is iterating over list of domain object and trying to replace value of an attribute using resource bundle.
Above code is resulting in weird parsing error

expecting ''', found '\r' @ line 95, column 132.

${domianObject.paymentMode })

```
                             ^
```

1 error

```
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:

Comment: Can you try with " instead of ' and check? AFAIK the ${x} replace doesn't work with single quotes i.e. '

Comment: Already tried but no luck !

Comment: infect I tried this as well
<g:message 
code="${domianObject.paymentMode}.label" 
default="Test" />
but that resulted in displaying just Test in the output

I am little surprised, thought this should be straight forward thing

Comment: Why is label on the outside? Shouldn't it be ${domianObject.paymentMode.label} ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that's a simple typo. Not domianObject but domainObject. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Nesting of gstring expressions can be a bit hairy, but once you're inside a `${}` you can use any Groovy expression so instead of the inner gstring you can say

```
${message(code:(domainObject.paymentMode  + '.label'), default:'Test')}
```

using normal string concatenation.